Trigger new live stream on my Facebook page programatically
I'm managing a local volleyball league Facebook page and would like to stream the live matches from my GoPro to this page. I wanted to automate things so when GoPro connects to the RTMP server and starts streaming my script (could be Python or everything else) would create a stream on Facebook page, fetch the FB stream key and pass it to the FFMpeg.
Is this goal achievable using FB API? I have verified developer account in FB and the page has ~1k likes. Do I need to create a Facebook app in order to be able to create live streams? Should this app be somehow public or can it be in a form of cli/python script?
I've tried to use the facebook API but could find the direct answer to my question
